# How to draw polygon overlay on Google-Maps in Android? and add the button like this?

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay, polygon, polyline

I need to finish my thesis.
I want to make like an GIS on my android.
All I need is build android application that can show the map, draw polygon overlay on it, add house button in it, and save as an image.
I'd already know how to show Google-Maps on my android, but I don't know how to draw polygon overlay on it.
All I need seems like this screenshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CcMIE.jpg

thank you.

Comment: have you tried googling "google map polygon"? have you tried looking at the source code of the app you got the screenshot of?

Comment: I got this screenshot from google map in web, I need it will be available on my Android app. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To overlay the two needed surfaces, you can use the merge tag. take a look at this [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-merge.html)